# How to find the intersection of a point and a line?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, trigonometry

I would like to find the intersection point of an point + direction and a Line.

- The point is located at the center of a polygon and the lines are the polygon edges.
- The direction is rotation in radians of the longest segment of the polygon.

To illustrate the problem I have I made a screenshot:

[image of the current state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gWc0.jpg)

You can see the center point, the longest segment of the polygon on the right + the beginning point of the longest segment, all in black color.

- The purple and red points are the intersection points my algorithm has found.
- The bottom and right intersection are right but on the left it found 2 intersection points, one of them is correct.
- The top intersection did not reached the edge of the polygon.
- The purple points should be the top and bottom intersection
- The smaller red point should be on the left and right of the polygon, as you can see they are partially mixed together.

My code:

First loop calculates the longest segment and the rotation of that segment. Second loop checks for intersection in the vertical and horizontal direction based on the rotation of the longest segment

```
let sqLongestSide = 0;
let longestSideXDiff = 0;
let longestSideYDiff = 0;

for (let i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    let pointFrom = coordinates[i - 1];
    let pointTo = coordinates[i];

    const xDiff = pointFrom[0] - pointTo[0];
    const yDiff = pointFrom[1] - pointTo[1];

    const sqDistance = Math.sqrt(xDiff * xDiff + yDiff * yDiff);

    const roundedDistance = Math.round(sqDistance * 100) / 100;
    const roundedLongestSide = Math.round(sqLongestSide * 100) / 100;

    if (roundedDistance > roundedLongestSide) {
        sqLongestSide = sqDistance;
        longestSideXDiff = xDiff;
        longestSideYDiff = yDiff;
    }
}

const rotation = Math.atan(longestSideYDiff / longestSideXDiff);

for (let i = 1; i < coordinates.length; i++) {

    let pointFrom = coordinates[i - 1];
    let pointTo = coordinates[i];

    const intersectionTopAndBottom = intersectionPoint(anchor, rotation, [pointFrom, pointTo]);

    if (intersectionTopAndBottom) {
        setPointStyle(drawContext, "#FF00FF", 20);
        drawContext.drawPoint(new Point(intersectionTopAndBottom));
        drawContext.drawLineString(new LineString([anchor, intersectionTopAndBottom]));
    }

    const intersectionLeftAndRight = intersectionPoint(anchor, (rotation + Math.PI / 2), [pointFrom, pointTo]);

    if (intersectionLeftAndRight) {
        setPointStyle(drawContext, "#FF0000", 10);
        drawContext.drawPoint(new Point(intersectionLeftAndRight));
        setLineStyle(drawContext, "#FF0000", 5);
        drawContext.drawLineString(new LineString([anchor, intersectionLeftAndRight]));
    }
```

The function to find the intersection looks like this:

```
function intersectionPoint(
  point: Coordinate,
  theta: number,
  line: Coordinate[]
): Coordinate {
  const x0 = Math.round(point[0] * 100) / 100;
  const y0 = Math.round(point[1] * 100) / 100;

  const x1 = Math.round(line[0][0] * 100) / 100;
  const y1 = Math.round(line[0][1] * 100) / 100;
  const x2 = Math.round(line[1][0] * 100) / 100;
  const y2 = Math.round(line[1][1] * 100) / 100;

  // Check if the line is vertical or horizontal
  if (x1 === x2) {
    // The line is vertical, so the intersection point is simply the point with the same x-coordinate as the line
    return [x1, y0];
  } else if (y1 === y2) {
    // The line is horizontal, so the intersection point is simply the point with the same y-coordinate as the line
    return [x0, y1];
  }

  // Convert the line to slope-intercept form
  const slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
  const intercept = y1 - slope * x1;

  // Convert the point and direction to slope-intercept form
  const slope2 = Math.tan(theta);
  const intercept2 = y0 - slope2 * x0;

  // Find the intersection point of the two lines
  const x = (intercept2 - intercept) / (slope - slope2);
  const y = slope * x + intercept;

  return [x, y];
}
```

I need just 4 intersection points but get more for this specfic polygon but for simple rectangle I get the right result.

EDIT:

Just to make it clear. I need to apply a rotation to the ray. This is the rotation of the longest segment, calculated in the first loop.

@Blindman67 your solution gave me the correct results for the first polygon, I just need that intersection "cross" to be rotated. Like in the following image:

[correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5Tlt.jpg)

the algorithm give me the following result:

[not correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaiDD.png)

Answer (score 0):

### Clarification

Clarifying my understanding of your problem.

If given a set of points **P<sub>1-6</sub>** and a point **A** find the points that intercept the projected point A along the x and y axis, points **B<sub>1-7</sub>**

[image: Illustration of problem described above]

Your function gave points **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, **B<sub>3</sub>**, **B<sub>4</sub>**, **B<sub>5</sub>**. However points **B<sub>4</sub>**, **B<sub>5</sub>** are incorrect

You say you only want 4 points, **B<sub>1</sub>**, **B<sub>2</sub>**, **B<sub>3</sub>**, **B<sub>6</sub>**

### Solution

It looks like the points of interest are only the points that are on the line segments created by the points **P<sub>1-6</sub>**

We can use a function the finds the intercept of a line (infinite length) and a line segment (finite length has a start and end) See example code below.

### Example code

The function `interceptLineSeg` will find the point on the line segment (including the start point and excluding the end point). If you include both the start and end points then you will (may due to floating point error) find the same point twice.

**Note** That floating point error may result in a point found twice. You may have to check if two found points are too close.

**Note** That if the point A is on a line (defined by poly edge segment) aligned to the x, or y axis then the point of intercept will depend on the direction of the points that make up the polygon (clockwise or anticlockwise)

```js
const TAU = Math.PI * 2;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const P2 = (x, y) => ({x, y});      // 2d point
const L2 = (p1, p2) => ({p1, p2});  // 2d line
const A = P2(100, 115);
const points =  [P2(140,20), P2(140, 140), P2(40, 140), P2(40, 115), P2(80, 80), P2(80, 50)];

function addCircle(p, r) {ctx.moveTo(p.x + r, p.y); ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, r, 0, TAU) }
function addLine(l) {  ctx.moveTo(l.p1.x, l.p1.y);  ctx.lineTo(l.p2.x, l.p2.y) }
function strokePath(points, close = false) {
  var i = 0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  while (i < points.length - 1) { addLine(L2(points[i ++], points[i])); }
  close && addLine(L2(points[0], points[points.length - 1]));
  ctx.stroke();
}
function markPoints(points, r) {
  var i = 0;
  ctx.beginPath();
  while (i < points.length) { addCircle(points[i++], r); }
  ctx.fill();
}

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0088ff";
ctx.fillStyle = "#0088ff";
strokePath(points, true);
markPoints(points, 5);

ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
ctx.fillStyle = "#ff0000";
strokePath([P2(A.x - 100, A.y), P2(A.x + 100, A.y)]);
strokePath([P2(A.x, A.y - 100), P2(A.x, A.y + 100)]);

markPoints([A], 5);

const iPoints = intercepts(A, points);
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
markPoints(iPoints, 5);
console.log("Points found: " + iPoints.length);

function interceptLineSeg(l, s){  // l is line, s is seg
    const v1x = l.p2.x - l.p1.x;
    const v1y = l.p2.y - l.p1.y;
    const v2x = s.p2.x - s.p1.x;
    const v2y = s.p2.y - s.p1.y;
    const c = v1x * v2y - v1y * v2x; // cross product of line vectors
    if (c !== 0) {                   // only if not parallel 
    
        // get unit pos of intercept on line segment
        const u = (v1x * (l.p1.y - s.p1.y) - v1y * (l.p1.x - s.p1.x)) / c;
        if (u >= 0 && u < 1) { // is intercept on segment (include only start)
            return P2(s.p1.x + v2x * u, s.p1.y + v2y * u);
        }
    }
    return; // returns undefined if no intercept
}


// a is point 
// p is array of points
function intercepts(a, p) {
    var i = 0;
    const hLine = L2(a, P2(a.x + 100, a.y));
    const vLine = L2(a, P2(a.x, a.y + 100));
    const wLine = L2();
    const intercepts = [];
    ahy = a.y;
    avx = a.x;
    avy = a.y + 100;
    while (i < p.length) {
        wLine.p1 = p[i];
        wLine.p2 = p[(i + 1) % p.length];
        const hl = interceptLineSeg(hLine, wLine);
        const vl = interceptLineSeg(vLine, wLine);
        if (hl) {
            intercepts.push(hl);
        } else if (vl) {
            intercepts.push(vl);
        }
        i ++;
    }
    return intercepts;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Comment: This works but not for every polygon it seems, see my edit for more details